# Removing all Spaces from the Password before submitting the Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to strip all the spaces from the Password field after I submit the Form.

This is what I wrote:-

```
   $(document).on("submit", "form#user-login", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var emailAdd = $("#edit-pass").val().replace(/ /g,'');
        $('#edit-pass').val(emailAdd);
        $('#user-login').submit();
   });
```

There is a problem though it throws this error:-

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

and well, it's not working either :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"Maximum call stack size exceeded"` usually means that there is a recursion without end condition. And that's what happens here.

You're calling `submit` from the `submit` event handling function, which triggers another call to the same function. Just remove the `e.preventDefault();` and return (not `false`) and it will be submitted.

Comment: Strangely, it doesn't do anything after I removed the submit line and replaced it with "return". It just became inactive ...

Comment: remove also the preventDefault.